# Bootstrap 3 navbar link with delayed popup menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, menu, hover, delay

I am trying to have a navbar link with a delayed popup menu. I do not want to use a normal dropdown as I want the user to be able to click on the main link, but if they hover for say 1 second then a poup menu will show.

I have created a code pen but it is not working right.

In my code pen I have created a Link in the navbar called "jobs" and if the user clicks this then they should navigate to what ever href is defined.

But if they hover then a menu is displayed. In my code pen I am using javascript to made the menu hover. But the menu will not go away when the user clicks elsewhere on the page.

https://codepen.io/iisfaq/pen/RJNJGN

```
  $('#btnJobs').hover(function (e) {
            //   e.stopPropagation();

            window.setTimeout(function () {

                $('#btnJobs').dropdown('toggle');
            }, 800);
        });
```

It also looks like the link no longer works once the popup is displayed as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a while to wait before do something, like that:

```
$('#btnJobs').hover(function (e) {
  //   e.stopPropagation();

  var start = new Date().getTime() + 800;
  while (new Date().getTime() < start) {
    //wait
  }

  //After
  $('#btnJobs').dropdown('toggle');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Refer Below Fiddle.

On unHover you want hide dropdown then Just replace your code with this.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/raskarvishal7/cz5f3kth/1/)

```
$(function(){
    $('#btnJobs').hover(function(){
            window.setTimeout(function () {
            $('#btnJobs').dropdown('toggle');
        }, 800);
    }, function(){
        $('#btnJobs').parent().removeClass('open');
    });
});
```

For Outside Click

```
$('#btnJobs').hover(function(){
           window.setTimeout(function () {
              $('#btnJobs').dropdown('toggle');
           }, 800);
     }

    $(document).click(function(){
         if($('#btnJobs').parent().hasClass('open')){
             $('#btnJobs').parent().removeClass('open');
         }
    })
```